# Figures missing from the list of figures when using hvfloat package

Tags: miktex, texworks

I'm using the hvfloat-Package to include figures. Unfortunately, some of them are missing from the list of figures. As soon as I set the nonFloat option to true, they reappear. As this looks ugly, it is no workaround for me. I've had a look at the hvfloat manual but couldn't come up with a solution. Can you help me? Thanks. Texworks 0.4.5 r1280, Miktex 2.9 64-bit.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\EUR{}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\usepackage[notlof,notlot,nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{author\hfill title\hfill}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{myred} {rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
  deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  % extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
  frame=single,                    % adds a frame around the code
  keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
  keywordstyle=\color{mymauve},       % keyword style
  language=Java,                 % the language of the code
  morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
  numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
  showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
  showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
  showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
  stringstyle=\color{blue},     % string literal style
  tabsize=1,                       % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  caption=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}

% set colors for links and URLs and meta data
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    pdftitle={foo},
    pdfsubject={bar},
    pdfauthor={author},
    pdfkeywords={key}
]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings

\newpage
\section{Testdokumentation}
\label{sec:testdokumentation}
\hvFloat[
    nonFloat=false,%
    capWidth=w,%
    capPos=b,%
    rotAngle=0,%
    objectPos=c%
    ]{figure}{%
        \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
        \setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.9,trim=0 0 0 0, clip=false]{image.png}} % trim: from left, bottom, right, top
    }{imagecaption}{img:imagelabel}
\end{document}
```

The lof file is empty, btw:
    \select@language {ngerman}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you *must* have the optional caption argument if you want that the figure appears in the list of figures.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Testdokumentation}
\label{sec:testdokumentation}

\hvFloat[
    nonFloat=false,
    capWidth=w,
    capPos=b,
    rotAngle=0,
    objectPos=c,
    ]{figure}{%
        \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
        \setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}%
        \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image.png}}%
    }[imagecaption]{imagecaption}{img:imagelabel}
\end{document}
```

I have removed all inessential packages for the MWE. Note that `a4wide` is deprecated and should *never* be used.

I have also removed the unnecessary `%` and added some required ones.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! Could you comment on why the % is necessary in the places where you put it?

Comment: @ScarOnTheSky Spaces around key-value pairs are automatically removed; on the other hand, you had three spaces in the contents of the figure, because there each end-of-line counts as a space in the output.